# Asynchronously downloading files via php script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

On my company's network, there's a page that generates a topographical range gradient KML based on points passed in through the URL.  The problem is that the page takes an average of 30 seconds to complete a request, and I need about 70 requests daily.  What I plan to do is have my office's website use a local copy and only re-download when the coordinates change.  But I'm having a hard time getting this to work asynchronously.  Right now I'm using $.get() to try  and load them asynchronously.  However, I'm getting no response from the website using get.  It returns a status 200 OK, but the line is highlighted in red in Firebug.  When I swap out that url for a kml hosted through our site, it returns 200 OK in black, and has the contents of the KML as the response.  Why would the remote tool not be downloading correctly?

Comment: Is the website you use at the same domain as the website where you try to `$.get` from?

Comment: No, but it's the same network.  I'm missing why it would matter, since the site generates a KML file and sends it to the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) prevents you from making requests to another domain. You either need to look into [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control) [if the browser and other site support it], JSONP [if other site support it], or a local proxy.

Comment: But shouldn't the site that returns a file just let me access that as a temp file or something?  I'm obviously missing something.  The site just returns a KML file, shouldn't my server be saving that as a temporary file?  If I do something like file_get_contents it's fine.  If there's a solution that's not jQuery, that's also fine.  I'd prefer it to be PHP, but I haven't been able to get it to download the files all at the same time without freezing my server until they're all done.

Comment: JavaScript can not access another domain. It has nothing to do with that server or your server. JavaScript runs on the client, not your server. You can write a proxy in a few lines of php code. [google](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+ajax+proxy)

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to send cross-domain AJAX requests. That could be a problem if you try to download a file with $.get from another domain.